# How similar or different are "recant", "repudiate", "renounce"

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

*Recant, repudiate, renounce* are synonyms of *abjure*. I'm unclear as to how these terms may be utilized in different sentences. I will be delighted to see them all in one sentence.

I seek efficient and effective applications and examples, rather than mere citations that could appear to be too obvious or banal.

Comment: *Recant, repudiate, and renounce are all synonyms of "abjure".*

Comment: Why would you want to use synonyms in a single sentence? Do you want to write a sentence multiple times,  each time using a different word?

Comment: Please try using a good dictionary.

Comment: no specific purpose, just to see how different they are (same sentence.) Also how similar they are (separate sentences.)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

The claimant recanted their statement, and renounced their claim on the prize since that claim was repudiated by the lotto commission based on the discovery of new information.

Answer (score 1):

Recant has the connotation of "taking back" something you have said publicly. Sometimes it seems to have the connotation of having been forced to do take back previous statements, with an attendant whiff of possible insincerity.

Renounce usually has the connotation that you have actually changed your mind. It has a more forceful connotation than "recant", although I do not think of renouncement as necessarily having a public component.

Repudiate also has a more forceful connotation. You can, and usually do, repudiate something you never believed in to begin with, although it is possible to repudiate something you used to believe.

Comment: Would you be likely to repudiate something you said yourself?

Comment: In the past, I have ofttimes repudiated things that I supposedly had said when I was in a less-than-sober state of mind. Apart from the allegations concerning my utterances, there never was any actual proof of the repudiated statements having been made by yours truly, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see these words as synonyms. I don't believe I've ever encountered 'abjure', so I can't comment on how they each relate to that word.

To my mind at least, 'recant' means to withdraw a previously-stated proposition, and it could possibly be done so in a sly or deliberately quiet manner.

'Repudiate' means to dispute the factual truth of something, or to bring somebody's integrity or worth into question.

'Renounce' means to disown or otherwise give up a belief or practice, and it has connotations of some kind of moral disdain towards whatever that belief or practice is.

Here's an attempt at all three in one sentence:

'The morning after the night before, their hangover-infused debrief resolved little: Tom, although embarrassed, could not bring himself to recant his views on the French, Dick repudiated the very suggestion that he had abducted Mrs Smith's porcelain hedgehog, and whilst in that moment Harry renounced drinking altogether, his commitment stumbled that very evening (as did he).'

Comment: perfect thank you :) exactly what I was looking for :) correct me if I'm wrong but I believed renounced could be used to describe a situation where a person or thing was disowned couldn't it? thanks :)